# Xpath XML Nokogiri - LIKE expression

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri, Ruby and Xpath to parse a large XML document of computer games.

To put what im trying to do in context... I have a large database of computer games, I want to lookup those computer games in an XML document. The issue I have is that the names can vary slightly, e.g 'Halo 4', 'Halo4', 'Halo: 4'

My XML block looks like this:

```
<prod id="695980453"><pId>NH485QS</pId><text><name>Metal Gear Solid HD Collection XBox 360</name><desc>Accept the mission and play three great chapters in the Metal Gear franchise with the Metal Gear Solid HD Collection. Included are Metal Gear Solid 2: Sons of Liberty, Metal Gear Solid 3: Snake Eater and Metal Gear Solid: Peace Walker. All three games are rendered in high-definition for the first time!</desc></text><uri><awTrack>http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=695980453&amp;a=161542&amp;m=3026</awTrack><awImage>http://images.productserve.com/preview/3026/695980453.jpg</awImage><mLink>http://tracking.searchmarketing.com/click.asp?aid=1719191667</mLink><mImage>http://images2.drct2u.com/content/images/products/nh/nh485/c01nh48550w.jpg</mImage></uri><price curr="GBP"><buynow>40.00</buynow><delivery>3.99</delivery></price><cat><awCatId>579</awCatId><awCat>Video Games</awCat><mCat>Main Menu|Electricals|Gaming &amp;amp; Consoles|Video Games</mCat></cat><brand><awBrandId>427</awBrandId><brandName>Xbox 360</brandName></brand></prod>
```

My xpath currently looks like:

```
game_result = file.at_xpath("//prod[text/name[text()=\"#{game.title}\"]]")
```

This works fine if the name matches exactly. I've tried to use the contains method but found that this was returning some weird results... e.g anything with just the word Halo in it, 'Halo Thunder' for example.

Any more suggestions would be great.

Comment: You could use `fn:translate` to change everything to a smaller-case transliteration and throw away everything but letters and digits. This is fine for the different "Halo" versions above, but would not be able to deal with "Halo IV" for example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I may end up doing something like that.

Comment: Added an example as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to find all differences, you might try to sanitize them by using `fn:translate($string, $map, $translate)`. It replaces every character in `$map` by its representation in `$translate`, if there is none (`$translate` is shorter) it gets ommitted.

For example (wrapped in a little bit of XPath 2.0 for demonstration, the `fn:translate` function is also available in XPath 1.0):

```
for $string in ('Halo 4', 'Halo: 4', 'Halo4', 'Halo-4')
return
  translate($string,
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 :.-_',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')
```

Output:

> halo4 halo4 halo4 halo4

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby is involved, you could over-search using XPath and then pare down the results using Ruby. For example:

```
# A magic method that returns something like /halo.+(4|iv)/i
title_regex = make_good_regex_from(game.title)
games = file.xpath("//prod").select do |prod|
  prod.at_xpath('./text/name').text =~ title_regex
end
```

It's sure to use more memory, and likely to be slower, but it's far more powerful than the text manipulation available in XPath 1.0.

<sub>If you need only the first matching product and not all, then use `find` instead of `select`.</sub>